# drawing with libcairo

Tags: c, svg

I try to draw with libcairo, it draws nothing. I downloaded the diagram sample, it works fine [draw.c], but code example from the site doesn't draw: like http://cairographics.org/samples/fill_and_stroke2/

why?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your **whole** code please.

Answer (score 0):

The code you linked to looks fine. But of course, it's not a complete program. Without seeing what code you've wrapped around the example to make it run, all I can guess is that you may need to call `cairo_show_page()` and `cairo_surface_flush()`.